# Does 'RedirectToAction' Calls the controller's constructor again?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction

I'm using ASP.NET MVC Core to build a practice project. I've noticed that inside my controller if the current method returns a redirect, such as `RedirectToAction("SomeAction")`, the controller gets constructed again before moving to the 'SomeAction' action.

Does that mean that `RedirectToAction` is actually performing a new HTTP Request and not just reusing the same request for 'SomeAction'?

Answer (score 2):

That is correct. According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx):

> Returns an HTTP 302 response to the browser, which causes the browser
>   to make a GET request to the specified action.

So it is effectively returning control all the way to the browser, which then issues a new request to the server.  You can use a tool like Fiddler to test this out and see the behavior.